# Angular CLI modify component generation

Tags: angular-cli

Is it possible to generate ADDITIONAL files when generating a component with the CLI?

Meaning, hey when I run ng g c my-component that it not only generates the component files and adds the necessary imports but also, I would like for it to generate some other files that I may want/need.

Perhaps I have some localization files for each component that I would like to generate at the same time. Can the generate be modified?